# Amazon EC2 IAM Policy: Restrict to modifying single security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM Policy in Amazon AWS which will allow access to view or edit/modify a single security group. I have followed the AWS documentation, but am unsuccessfully able to make this policy work. The policy created is below:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123456789123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000000000000:security-group/sg-a123a1a1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Yes, I do realize that I have a redundant action, but I noticed you are able to specify Describe Security Group, but no option for Modify; therefore "*" was my only option; Thankfully, the resource should allow me to restrict this action to a single security group.

Answer (score 2):

It is partly possible, please see https://serverfault.com/questions/575487/use-iam-to-allow-user-to-edit-aws-ec2-security-groups, it's actually possible to constrain editing to just one group, but I didn't get listing of just one group to work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1413232782000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [               
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"              
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1413232782001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",                
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<accountid>:security-group/sg-<id>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I managed to put together and it works great!

Create the following policy and add it to a User Group or make one:

Update the items that are in {BRACKETS}

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:{REGION}:{ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:security-group/{NSG-ID}",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnEquals": {
                "ec2:Vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:{REGION}:{ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:vpc/{VPC-ID}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupReferences",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeStaleSecurityGroups"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Well, it looks like the code formatter is not working right with this, but you can read the references here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_securitygroups-vpc.html

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

You can add new rule to security group like

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name MySecurityGroup --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr 203.0.113.0/24
```

And also change the tags as well.

Comment: OP is talking about the issue he faced while creating IAM policy for managing a security group. This answer is about using aws cli to manage a security group